# Trying to get the associated value from an Enum at runtime in Java

Tags: java, enums

I want to accomplish something like the following (my interest is in the toInt() method). Is there any native way to accomplish this? If not, how can I get the integer associated with an enum value (like in C#) ?

```
enum Rate {
 VeryBad(1),
 Bad(2),
 Average(3),
 Good(4),
 Excellent(5);

 private int rate;

 private Rate(int rate) {
  this.rate = rate;
 }

 public int toInt() {
  return rate;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java enums are not like C# enums. They are objects as opposed to just a name for an integer constant. The best you could do is look at the hash code for the objects, but that will not give you any real meaningful/ useful information in the sense I believe you are looking for. The only real way to do it is as in your example code assigning a property to the enum and a means for accessing it (either via a method, or as a public final field).

Comment: But how to implement that method? My toInt() as far as I can tell won't work in java. I don't have a way to call it.

Comment: You call it on the enum value itself: Rate.Excellent.toInt(), or if you were to make the field rate public (and in good style final as well) you could say Rate.Excellent.rate.

Answer (score 2):

In "Effective Java" Joshua Bloch recommends the following pattern:

```
private static final Map<Integer, Rate> intToEnum = new HashMap<Integer, Rate>();
static
{
   for(Rate rate: values())
      intToEnum.put(Integer.valueOf(rate.toInt()), rate);
}
public static Rate fromInt(int intVal)
{
   return intToEnum.get(Integer.valueOf(intVal));
}
```

Comment: He also suggests avoiding `ordinal()`, as "Most programmers will have no use for this method." http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29

Comment: to place inside enum, great thing!

Comment: But here defining `public int toInt() {return ordinal() + 1;}` does the job. Whatever reasons may exist to avoid ordinal(), inside the enum class they're not valid.

Comment: sure they are.  Ordinal simply has to do with the order in which the fields are defined.  What happens when someone goes and inserts another value in the middle?  Your entire order is thrown off.  So if you've save the oridinal value to a file, db, or whatever, it's now innaccurate. If you really need int values associated with an enum, you should have a code assigned value (as in the code above).

Comment: @Matt What happens if someone goes and deletes the whole class? What if she formats your hard drive? If you insert an Enum value in the middle instead of simply appending it, you must have a reason for this and you must know what you're doing. Concerning storing the values in a DB I tend to agree that using names is better (unless someone goes and fixes a typo in an enum constant!).

Answer (score 0):

```
return enumVal.ordinal();
```

(see the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()))

Edit: I originally misread your code; you seem to be doing all the int/enum conversion stuff manually, when Java handles all that. You really shouldn't need to use ints, you can just use the enums as a separate type. As the javadoc says, it's unlikely you'll ever actually want the int associated with a particular value; "Good" and "4" don't have any connection to each other, 4 just happens to be its position in the enum

Comment: If I have a set of objects with rating, I'll want to know what is the average rate. So manipulating them as integers is not only an advantage, it's a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question but an enum instance has an ordinal() method returning its position as an int. But it is bad practice to rely on it, the instance field as shown in your example is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

As enum is treated as an object in Java. To get the value ofrrate associated with your enum just write the following code

```
return enumValue.toInt();
```

In this case enumValue stored the current enum instance. So for example

```
Rate enumValue = Rate.Good;
enumValue.toInt(); // return value 4;
```

Alternatively if you want to know what is its ordinal then return enumValue.ordinal();
However after assigning some value to an enum I do not understand why you would need its ordinal.